# Avro file decoding from array of bytes

Tags: java, avro

I have my method which get the gcp bucket name and object name, so it can get file from gcp storage. This file is avro.I am able to get array of bytes of this file. How do i decode it to object ?
I tried code below, but it throw indexOutOfBoundException. What am i doing wrong ?

```
byte[] bytes = storageRepository.getBlob(bucketName, objectName).getContent();
        DatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(Client.getClassSchema());
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null);
        try {
            GenericData.Record record = reader.read(null, decoder);
            System.out.println(record);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException();
        }
```

Full stack trace look like this

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 22 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:284) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readField(SpecificDatumReader.java:136) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader.readRecord(SpecificDatumReader.java:123) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153) ~[avro-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.nazar.fileparsing.service.ClientService.getFile(ClientService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.nazar.fileparsing.controller.ClientController.parseAvroAndWriteToBigQuery(ClientController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace. And why are you throwing a RuntimeException() with no message and no cause?

Comment: posted stacktrace

Comment: Looks like the file is not an AVRO file since the library is not able to parse it correctly. Or it could be a bug in the library.

Comment: This looks like a very similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614343/avro-deserialization-error-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: i have seen this question but i did not found solution there.

Comment: Follow the links on the accepted answer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2095

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is very weird. When I create avro file i serialize object directly to file, and when i get it from storage i'm trying to deserialize it as array of bytes because i get data in this format, but this is where i get exception. But if i serialize my object to byte array firstly and then write it to the file, i am able to deserialize it later, but i'm not sure this is avro file anymore.
Here is my code. The one which commented is an old one.

```
private void generateAvro(Client client) throws IOException {
//        DatumWriter<Client> clientDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(Client.class);
//        DataFileWriter<Client> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(clientDatumWriter);
//        dataFileWriter.create(Client.getClassSchema(), new File("client.avro"));
//        dataFileWriter.append(client);
//        dataFileWriter.close();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
        DatumWriter<Client> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(Client.getClassSchema());
        writer.write(client, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        out.close();
        byte[] serializedBytes = out.toByteArray();
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newclient.avro")) {
            fos.write(serializedBytes);
        }

    }
```

Also i`ve tried to use method of Blob downloadTo() to create file and deserialize it later and it worked to. But i`m not sure about perfomance.